# make a colorbar in scatter plot in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, scatter-plot, colorbar

I have the following dataframe (df):

```
sza              dif 

5                12 
 
6                9 

9                12

23              1323

56              122

34              3132

6               454

34              23
```

I have made a scatter plot:

```
plt.scatter ( x = df['sza'] , y = df['dif'] )
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/clGsf.png

I want to make a colorbar of the values of sza that will show with different color how many dif values correspond to a sza value

for example:

- 10 dif values corresponding to a sza value , this sza value in the colourbar will be green
- 20 dif values  corresponding to a sza value , this sza value in the colourbar will be red
  ....

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the scatter plot function of `matplotlib` and creating a custom color map based on the count of the `dif` values corresponding to each `sza` value. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Your dataframe
data = {'sza': [5, 6, 9, 23, 56, 34, 6, 34], 'dif': [12, 9, 12, 1323, 122, 3132, 454, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by 'sza' and count 'dif' values
sza_counts = df.groupby('sza')['dif'].count().reset_index(name='count')

# Merge the original dataframe with the counts
df = df.merge(sza_counts, on='sza')

# Normalize counts to be between 0 and 1
df['norm_count'] = df['count'] / df['count'].max()

# Create a custom color map based on the normalized count values
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
colors = cmap(df['norm_count'])

# Plot the scatter plot with the custom color map
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x=df['sza'], y=df['dif'], c=colors)

# Add a colorbar to the plot
cbar = plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(0, df['count'].max())))
cbar.set_label('Number of dif values')

plt.xlabel('sza')
plt.ylabel('dif')
plt.show()
```

You can also modify the code to display the `sza` values in the colorbar label instead of the normalized count values. You can achieve this by changing the colorbar tick labels to the corresponding `sza` values:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Your dataframe
data = {'sza': [5, 6, 9, 23, 56, 34, 6, 34], 'dif': [12, 9, 12, 1323, 122, 3132, 454, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by 'sza' and count 'dif' values
sza_counts = df.groupby('sza')['dif'].count().reset_index(name='count')

# Merge the original dataframe with the counts
df = df.merge(sza_counts, on='sza')

# Normalize counts to be between 0 and 1
df['norm_count'] = df['count'] / df['count'].max()

# Create a custom color map based on the normalized count values
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
colors = cmap(df['norm_count'])

# Plot the scatter plot with the custom color map
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x=df['sza'], y=df['dif'], c=colors)

# Add a colorbar to the plot
cbar = plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(0, df['count'].max())))
cbar.set_label('sza values')

# Set colorbar tick labels to the corresponding 'sza' values
sza_values = sza_counts['sza'].values
norm_sza_values = sza_counts['count'] / sza_counts['count'].max()
cbar.set_ticks(norm_sza_values)
cbar.set_ticklabels(sza_values)

plt.xlabel('sza')
plt.ylabel('dif')
plt.show()
```

Comment: first of all thank u for the help.
do you know how can i change your code in order to see in the colorbar label the sza values and not the normalised ?

Comment: You are welcome. I added a modified part in my response to answer your question